# Splitting of a string

Tags: java

I have a string like

```
<YYYY>-<MM>-<DD>_ABC_<ID>_<BKN>_<HH><MM><SS>
```

I want to split the string in such a way that the result should look like this:

```
<YYYY>
-
<MM>
-
<DD>
_
<ABC>
_
<ID>
_
<BKN>
_
<HH>
<MM>
<SS>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want the `_` as well as `-` as *seperate Strings* ?

Comment: Hi TheLostMind, Thanks for the reply. Yes i want both  '_' and '-' as separate strings :)

Comment: The ABC will be <ABC>?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s = "<YYYY>-<MM>-<DD>_ABC_<ID>_<BKN>_<HH><MM><SS>";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "_|\\-", true);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: This will not print the underscores and hyphens as expected in the output by the OP

Comment: Still  , the last token of your output will be <HH><MM><SS>,however <HH>,<MM> and <SS> must be in separate lines(new line)... ...keep grinding

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way, may look dirty, but will serve your purpose:

```
    String teststring="<YYYY>-<MM>-<DD>_ABC_<ID>_<BKN>_<HH><MM><SS>";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<YYYY>(.*)<MM>(.*)<DD>(.*)ABC(.*)<ID>(.*)<BKN>(.*)<HH>(.*)<MM>(.*)<SS>(.*)").matcher(teststring);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("<YYYY>\n" + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("<MM>\n" + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("<DD>\n" + m.group(3));
        System.out.println("<ABC>\n" + m.group(4));
        System.out.println("<ID>\n" + m.group(5));
        System.out.println("<BKN>\n" + m.group(6));
        System.out.println("<HH>\n" + m.group(7));
        System.out.println("<MM>\n" + m.group(8));
        System.out.println("<SS>\n" + m.group(9));
    }
```

Comment: You are assuming that the `<>` are literally in the source string, the format looks like a full date and time, with some extra stuff (and missing some other attributes like `:` separating hours, minutes and seconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1987-07-31_ABC_<ID>_<BKN>_<HH><MM><SS>";
    List < String > result = new ArrayList < String > ();
    String token = "";
    for (Character c: str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '-' || c == '_') {
            result.add(token);
            token = "";
            result.add(c.toString());
        } else {
            token += c;
        }
    }
    if (token != "") {
        result.add(token);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "<YYYY>-<MM>-<DD>_ABC_<ID>_<BKN>_<HH><MM><SS>";

    String a = s.replaceAll("[^-|_]", "");
    String[] b = s.replaceAll("[-_<>]", " ").trim().split("\\s+");

    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println("<" + b[i] + ">");       
        if(i < a.length()) System.out.println(a.charAt(i));
    }
```

or just

```
    String s = "<YYYY>-<MM>-<DD>_ABC_<ID>_<BKN>_<HH><MM><SS>";
    String[] c = s.replaceAll("-", "\n-\n").replaceAll("_", "\n_\n").replaceAll("><", ">\n<").split("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(c[i].indexOf("<") < 0 && c[i].length() > 1 ? "<" + c[i] + ">" : c[i]);   
    }
```

...

```
<YYYY>
-
<MM>
-
<DD>
_
<ABC>
_
<ID>
_
<BKN>
_
<HH>
<MM>
<SS>
```